# python script removes file extension

Tags: python

I have some video files

```
A Single Man (2009).avi
Accident (2009).mkv
Adventureland (2009).mp4
```

I use a python script that rename in this way

```
A Single Man (2009) [Drama]
Accident (2009) [Thriller]
Adventureland (2009) [Comedy]
```

What is the problem ? Script removes file extension. I don't understand why

**Part 1** : the function makes an API request to TMDb to search for a movie with the specified name and year, using the supplied API key. If the request was successful, it extracts the movie data from the response.

```
import os
import re
import requests

# Replace "YOUR_API_KEY" with your TMDb API key
api_key = 'My Api KEY'

# Let's create a function to get the movie ID from TMDb
def get_movie_id(name, year):
  # We encode the name of the movie to insert it in the URL
  name_encoded = requests.utils.quote(name)

  # We build the URL of the API request
  url = f'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={api_key}&query={name_encoded}&year={year}'

  # We send the API request
  response = requests.get(url)

  # We verify that the request was successful
  if response.status_code == 200:
    # We extract the movie data from the response
    data = response.json()
```

**Part 2**: after getting the search results from the API request response, the code checks that there are search results. If there are, it takes the first movie of the search results and extracts the movie ID from it. Then, it returns the movie ID. If there are no search results or if the API request was unsuccessful, the function returns None.

```
    # We verify that there are search results
    if data['total_results'] > 0:
      # Let's take the first movie of the search results
      movie = data['results'][0]

      # We extract the movie ID from the data
      movie_id = movie['id']

      return movie_id
    else:
      return None
  else:
    return None
```

**Part 3**: this code defines a function called get_movie_genre that takes one argument movie_id, which represents the ID of a movie. The function then makes an API request to TMDb to get the movie data with the specified ID, using the supplied API key. If the request is successful, it extracts the film genre from the obtained data and returns it. If the request was unsuccessful, the function returns None.

```
# Let's create a function to get the movie genre from TMDb
def get_movie_genre(movie_id):
  # We build the URL of the API request
  url = f'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}?api_key={api_key}'

  # We send the API request
  response = requests.get(url)

  # We verify that the request was successful
  if response.status_code == 200:
    # We extract the movie data from the response
    data = response.json()

    # We extract the film genre from the data
    genre = data['genres'][0]['name']

    return genre
  else:
    return None
```

**Part 4**: this code is a loop that iterates through all the files in the current directory. For each file, the code checks that it is a video file (ending in .avi or .mp4). If the file is a video, the code extracts the movie name and year from the filename using a regular expression. Then, the code looks up the movie on TMDb using the get_movie_id function we saw earlier.

If the movie is found, the code gets the genre of the movie using the get_movie_genre function we saw earlier. If the genre is found, the code constructs a new filename using the movie name, year, and genre. If the new name doesn't already exist, the code prints the old file name and the new computed name. Finally, the code renames the file to the new name.

```
# We loop over the files in the directory
for file in os.listdir():
  # We verify that the file is a video file
  if file.endswith('.avi') or file.endswith('.mp4'):
    # We extract the movie name and year from the file name
    match = re.search(r'(.*) \(((?:19|20)\d\d)\)', file)

    name = match.group(1)
    year = match.group(2)

    # We search for the movie on TMDb
    movie_id = get_movie_id(name, year)

    # We verify that the movie has been found
    if movie_id:
      # We get the genre of the film
      genre = get_movie_genre(movie_id)

      # Let's verify that the genus has been found
      if genre:
        # Let's construct the new file name
        new_name = f'{name} ({year}) [{genre}]'

        # We check if a file with the new name already exists
        if not os.path.exists(new_name):
          # Stampa il nome del file e il nuovo nome calcolato
          print(f'{file} -> {new_name}')

    # Let's rename the file
    os.rename(file, new_name)
```

Comment: The regular expression matches the name and year, and throws away the extension.

Comment: Have you debugged this code?

Comment: os.rename changes full file name (with extension). So you need to parse extension for each file and add it to new_name variable.

Comment: @JohnGordon `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\film\rename2.py", line 67, in <module>
    extension = match.group(3)
IndexError: no such group` - I try to edit in this way `match = re.search(r'(.*) \(((?:19|20)\d\d)\)\.\w+$', file)`

    `name = match.group(1)`
    `year = match.group(2)`
    `extension = match.group(3)`

    `# We search for the movie on TMDb`
    `movie_id = get_movie_id(name, year)`

    `# We verify that the movie has been found`
    `if movie_id:`
      `# We get the genre of the film`
      `genre = get_movie_genre(movie_id)`

Comment: `# Let's verify that the genre has been found
      if genre:
        # Let's construct the new file name
        new_name = f'{name} ({year}) [{genre}].{extension}'`

Comment: @JohnGordon ok, I fixed it by editing the regex correctly `match = re.search(r'(.*) \(((?:19|20)\d\d)\)\.(\w+)$', file)`